# Take limit in p-adic integer ring: the difference between $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n!}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n}$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $L / \mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite field extension. Let $\mathcal{O}_L$ its valuation ring (ring of local integers) in $L$, $\mathfrak{m}_L$ be the unique maximal ideal, and the cardinality of the residue field $\mathbb{F}$ is $q$.

I am hoping to show that for any $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n!} =  \begin{cases}
0, \quad \alpha \in \mathfrak{m}_L, \\
1, \quad \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L^{\times}. \end{cases} $$

Here is the proof that I have read before:

- For $\alpha \in \mathfrak{m}_L$, since $\vert \alpha \vert_p < 1$, the sequence $\{ \vert \alpha \vert_p^{n!} \}$ tends to zero.
- For $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L^{\times}$, we count $\# (\mathcal{O}_L / \mathfrak{m}_L^{r+1})^{\times}  = q^r(q-1)$ Then $\alpha^{q^r(q-1)} \equiv 1 \bmod{\mathfrak{m}_L^{r+1}}$. Therefore,
  $$
  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n!} = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{q^r(q-1)} = 1.
  $$

**My question is: where had I used the property of "$n!$"**? In other words, by simply replacing $n!$ by $n$ everywhere in the proof, it seems that I have "proved "
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n} =  \begin{cases}
0, \quad \alpha \in \mathfrak{m}_L, \\
1, \quad \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L^{\times}. \end{cases} $$

**Hence I must have misunderstood something but I cannot figure it out.** It seems that the only place that I do not fully understand is the equality
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n!} = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{q^r(q-1)}.
$$
Could someone help me to explain why this hold or say why
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{n} = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \alpha^{q^r(q-1)}.
$$
may not hold?

Sorry for such a stupid question, and thank you all for commenting and answering!

Comment: The first part is fine with $n$ replaced by $n!$, but you need divisibility results for $n!$ to make the second work, right? Like what if $\alpha=-1$? What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n$?

Comment: The first part does not work with $n$ instead of $n!$ either. The point is that $n!$ is divisible by higher and higher powers of $p$ as $n$ grows (without ever "falling back"), which is obviously not true for $n$, which ever so often is not divisible by $p$ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\nu$ as the largest natural number for which $n!$ is divisible by $p^{\nu-1}(p-1)=\phi(p^\nu)$. Then $|\alpha^{n!}-1|=p^{-\nu}$ in the $p$-adic norm. What happens with $n!$, but not just $n$, is that $\nu$ is both (nonstrictly) monotonically increasing and unbounded, conditions which force $|\alpha^{n!}-1|$ to converge to $0$.